# Unable to compare string in debug console

Tags: c++, string, g++

There is function which I am debugging in C++ using the Debug Console in vscode: 
`bool test2(std::string keys[], int data[], int max, std::string &error)`
If i type keys[i] in debug console it shows the value `"unbet"` 
In Debug console if I evaluate "unbet"=="unbet" it shows false 
If I do `"unbet"==keys[i]` it shows `Can't do that binary op on that type` 
If I do `"unbet".compare(keys[i])` it shows `Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a struct or union`
 I am not able to understand this behavior. It contradicts the logical thing. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: String literals like `"unbet"` are of of type `const char[]`, not `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

The std::string has the overloaded == operator. So, the type std::string should be left side of the comparison operator: `keys[i] == "unbet"` 
Ok, forget about Yoda style there.